# Calculate ratio $\frac{p^{3n}}{(\frac{p}{2})^{3n}}$

Tags: ratio

How do I calculate this ratio? I do not know even where to begin.

$$\frac{p^{3n}}{(\frac{p}{2})^{3n}}$$

Thanks

Comment: The edits here have changed the question.

Comment: @MarkBennet OP changed it himself. view the edit history

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, sorry. I said that in the comment description.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Thanks, I was trying to work out what had happened, and making a mess of it.

Comment: Note that $\cfrac {A^k}{B^k}=\left(\cfrac AB\right)^k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the original question:

$$
\frac{p^{3n}}{\frac{p^{3n}}{2}} = 
\frac{p^{3n}}{\frac{p^{3n}}{2}} \cdot 1 =
\frac{p^{3n}}{\frac{p^{3n}}{2}} \cdot \frac{2}{2} =
\frac{p^{3n}\cdot 2}{\frac{p^{3n}}{2} \cdot 2} =
\frac{p^{3n}\cdot 2}{p^{3n}\cdot 1} =
\frac{p^{3n}}{p^{3n}} \cdot \frac 2 1 =
1\cdot \frac 2 1 = 2.
$$

In general we have
$$
\frac{A}{\frac p q} = \frac{A\cdot q}{\frac p q \cdot q} = A\cdot\frac{q}{p},
$$
so dividing by $\frac p q$ is the same as multiplying by $\frac q p$. Using this you also get
$$
\frac{p^{3n}}{\frac{p^{3n}}{2}} = p^{3n}\cdot\frac{2}{p^{3n}} = 2.
$$

---

For your updated question we use $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^k = \frac{p^k}{q^k}$ to obtain
$$
\frac{p^{3n}}{\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^{3n}} = 
\frac{p^{3n}}{\left(\frac{p^{3n}}{2^{3n}}\right)} = 
p^{3n} \cdot \frac{2^{3n}}{p^{3n}} = 2^{3n}.
$$

Comment: (+1)... but little *verbose* don't you think?

Comment: heads up question got changed

Comment: @Sabyasachi For this kind of question I like to stress every single step, since this question is about the very nature of dealing with fractions.

Comment: @Christoph thank you for the help. If I want to read more on this, what should I search for? Algebraic ratios?

Comment: @Sorin Take a look at [Arithmetic with fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Arithmetic_with_fractions) in the wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{A^k}{\left(\frac{A}2\right)^k}=\frac{A^k}{\frac{A^k}{2^k}}=A^k\cdot\left(\frac{A^k}{2^k}\right)^{-1}=A^k\cdot\frac{2^k}{A^k}=2^k$$

Comment: What is wrong with $p$ that makes you use $A$?

Comment: @vonbrand Nothing, A is larger, hence easier to read. But changing p to A and 3n to k is also a way to suggest that the result is general (the next step would to replace 2 by B).

Comment: @vonbrand Asking for the author's intent (and receiving an answer) is one thing. Deciding to modify the answer to follow your personal whim is another. Please do not do that.